# having issues to validate form using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, xhtml

On this form when I enter the email address correctly and leaves the name field as a blank, the page is submitting and the javacript not running. Otherwise its working fine.

Please someone help me to solve this JavaScript.

```
function validateform(data)
{
    var validField = "";
    var namevalid=/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    if(data.name.value == ""){validField += "- Please Enter Your Name\n";}
    else if(data.name.value.search(namevalid)==-1){validField += "- Entered Name contains Numbers or Symbols\n";}
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(data.email.value)){
        return true;
        }
        validField += "- Please Enter A Valid E-mail Address\n";
        alert(validField);
        return false;
}


<form name="data" onsubmit="return validateform(this);" action="some.php" method="post">
<div>
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="20"  maxlength="20"/></div>

<div>
<label>E- mail Address:</label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="20"  maxlength="30"/></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Now!"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refactor your code a little bit. At the minute if the email address is valid your return true out of the function regardless of the name field.

```
function validateform(data) {
    var validField = "";
    var isValid = false;
    var namevalid = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    if (data.name.value == "") {
        validField += "- Please Enter Your Name\n";
    }
    else if (data.name.value.search(namevalid) == -1) { 
        validField += "- Entered Name contains Numbers or Symbols\n"; 
        }
    if (!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(data.email.value))) {
        validField += "- Please Enter A Valid E-mail Address\n";
    };
    if (validField == "") {
        isValid = true;
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        alert(validField);
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need little change in your code. Problem is because `function validateform()` always returning false irrespective of email validation. Test below working page along with your code. You should add alert and return false in `else {}` block.

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateform(data)
{
    var validField = "";
    var namevalid=/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    if(data.name.value == ""){validField += "- Please Enter Your Name\n";}
    else if(data.name.value.search(namevalid)==-1){validField += "- Entered Name contains Numbers or Symbols\n";}
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(data.email.value)){
        return true;
     }
     else {
        validField += "- Please Enter A Valid E-mail Address\n";
        alert(validField);
        return false;
        }
}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form name="data" onsubmit="return validateform(this);" action="some.php" method="post">
<div>
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="20"  maxlength="20"/></div>
<div>
<label>E- mail Address:</label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="20"  maxlength="30"/></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Now!"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your function between `<script>` tags, other than that this looks ok to me.

Comment: He probably posted a snippet, otherwise he would see all the JS on the screen and know something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why this is failing, but the function isn't called at all. Might be the `onsubmit`.

Why don't you use a library like jQuery? 
Have a look at this example, this works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tR3XQ/1/

```
$("form[name=data]").submit(function(){

    var validField = "";
    var namevalid=/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/;
    if(data.name.value == ""){validField += "- Please Enter Your Name\n";}
    else if(data.name.value.search(namevalid)==-1){validField += "- Entered Name contains Numbers or Symbols\n";}
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(data.email.value)){
        return true;
    }
    validField += "- Please Enter A Valid E-mail Address\n";
    alert(validField);
    return false;

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a check for a value in validField for the email check otherwise it is ignored

```
if (validField.length = 0 && /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(data.email.value)){
  return true;
}
validField += "- Please Enter A Valid E-mail Address\n";
alert(validField);
return false;
```